# Accidentally deleted the Vendor folder

Tags: magento2, composer

I accidentally deleted the vendor folder in my Magento 2 installation and I'm getting an autoload error and I also noticed that the env file is missing, is there any way to solve the problem ?
I also read that I can do `composer install` but will that affect my data ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`composer install` will recreate the vendor folder only. To recreate the .env file (app/etc/env.php) you'll need to reinstall Magento.

Comment: Still not resolving after did "Composer install" https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/319343/57334 any help thanks @Luigi T.

Comment: still the same error?

Answer (score 2):

vendor folder is just a deployment folder that comes from the commmand composer install.

I assume composer is installed on your machine, open a terminal and from the root of your Magento site, run `composer install`. Then your site should be back up as normal.

Comment: I ran the command as you said but instead I'm now getting a 500 error, any ideas ? Thank you so much by the way.

Comment: 500 is a server error: you should see in either magento log or your webserver log, what the error details is

Comment: Just a permission error :) fixed. Thank you again

Comment: @HerveTribouilloy composer install not resolving my issue, any help thanks https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/319343/57334